# Draw from e.ClipRectangle in OnPaint

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics

I am intentionally calling

```
Me.Invalidate(MyDesiredRepaintRectangle)
```

in my UserControl.

In the OnPaint event I want to draw from a buffer bitmap onto the e.Graphics:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
  If Not _Buffer Is Nothing Then
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_Buffer, e.ClipRectangle)
  End If
End Sub
```

But I am doing something wrong in the line

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(_Buffer, e.ClipRectangle)
```

... I think. Currently the entire _Buffer is drawn in a stretched way so that it fits in the e.ClipRectangle.

_Buffer has just the same size as the usercontrol.

I am unsure how to draw just the required portion onto the e.Graphics without any stretching.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
    If Not _Buffer Is Nothing Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_Buffer, e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    End If
```